# How to snapshot-test a component that does async data loading using react-testing-library?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, snapshot-testing

So far, in the projects I'm working on, I usually snapshot-test my components that does async data loading this way:

```
describe('MyComponent component', () =>{
    test('Matches snapshot', async () => {
        fetch.mockResponse(JSON.stringify(catFacts));

        const { asFragment } = render(<MyComponent />);
        await waitFor(() => expect(asFragment()).toMatchSnapshot());
    })
})
```

I find it very handy, because it allows to have a snapshot containing the different states of the component (loading, errors, loaded data).

The thing is that I just found out that this method was [not recommended at all](https://github.com/testing-library/eslint-plugin-testing-library/blob/master/docs/rules/no-wait-for-snapshot.md), and that the latest updates of the @testing-library/react package don't allow me to test my components this way anymore.

According to the eslint rules of the package, I would have to modify my code like this:

```
describe('MyComponent component', () =>{
    test('Matches snapshot', () => {
        fetch.mockResponse(JSON.stringify(catFacts));

        const { asFragment } = render(<MyComponent />);
        expect(asFragment()).toMatchSnapshot();
    })
})
```

It works, but the generated snapshot contains only the initial state of the component (in this case, "loading").

How would you do in this situation to efficiently snapshot-test a component loading data asynchronously?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are on the right track. The only thing left is to wait for your data to be loaded before you make your assertion.

```
describe('MyComponent component', async () =>{
    test('Matches snapshot', () => {
        fetch.mockResponse(JSON.stringify(catFacts));
        
        const { asFragment } = render(<MyComponent />);

        await waitForElementToBeRemoved(screen.getByText('loading'));

        expect(asFragment()).toMatchSnapshot();
    })
})
```

I used the `loading` text since you mentioned it on your question. But you can also wait for your data to appear on screen:

```js
await screen.findByText('something that comes from the mocked data');
```

Great job on noticing the `waitFor` issue and fixing it!

Comment: Oh, I hadn't thought of that. Clever and efficient!

Comment: What is `screen` here?

Comment: @tibbe does this help https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/about/#screen ?